# Block element after inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Now, the inline elements have `display: inline-block`. I need it to vertical align them. The block element is `display: block`.

This gives the following result (first image):

[image]

Since I want the pink element (block) to be on the right, if I try to set it to `float: right`, I get the other elements misplaced to the left leaving a margin on the right corresponding to the width of the block element. Any help?

Comment: What's your CSS? And could you maybe [post a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), to make it easier for us to help you (and also replicate your problem)?

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap pink block in a `div` and set the pink block to `float:right` there.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-inner clearfix">
        <div class="block" style="float:right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If there is content aber this inner wrapper you can add a clearfix class - because floating elements don't give their parent element a height:

```
    .clearfix:after {
        content:"";
        display:table;
        clear:both;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="inline-block"></div><!-- remove the whitespace
 --><div class="inline-block"></div><!-- because inline-blocks
 --><div class="inline-block"></div><!-- dont fully collapse whitespace
 --><div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  text-align: right; /* moves inline-blocks to the right */
  position: relative; /* to give context for absolute positioning of .block */
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f40;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /* move the block to the far right of #wrapper */
}
```

e.g: http://jsbin.com/etuxab/2/edit